# Plotly: Downloading Data in Real Time

Tags: csv, download, real-time, plotly

Is it possible to stream/download CSV data files from a live Plotly chart using API access in real time? I am setting up a system that accepts data from various sensors and plots it online using Plotly with following requirements:

- data has to be accessible from multiple locations/ multiple users
- API level access to actual data (numbers in CSV or alike) in realtime (a few seconds lag is acceptable)

Would Plotly be the right tool for this? I couldn't find any resource on downloading data in real time through API level access on their site.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no API for collecting steam data through plotly - the streaming service is intended for displaying data and the data is not persisted.

If you are plotting data that you are collecting realtime, you should be able to aggregate it and save it to a database or CSV at the same time you stream to Plotly for display.

Comment: Thanks Miklos, it'd sure be handy to have the feature though.